# How to deal deal with Typescript and Promisify / PromisifyAll

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, bluebird

I am wondering how TypeScript developers are handling Promisify and PromisifyAll and losing all types and code hints. Am I missing something obvious, a tool that helps us out here?

*I feel like 'PrmosifyAll @types/module' has got to be a project someone worked on.*

I'm hoping I'm missing something obvious because right now, typescript feels lacking for the first time in a long time.

Comment: Yes, typescript has a problem when you replace all methods of an object with closures that manipulate the arguments before calling the original methods/functions. Interfaces tend to get a bit fuzzy after that. There is no *good* tool for that. The promisifying should not be necessary in the first place *(and will problably be obsolete/deprecated in a few years as promises are replacing callbacks)* but until then, the best you can do is write declaration files for the promisified API; and maybe you publish them so others don't have to do the same work.

Comment: Maybe related: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19023